# Error while trying to program my ATmega16A with extreme burner

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, programmer

Whenever I want to burn the hex file on my chip, the following error message always appears:

> Power On Failed
>
> Cannot communicate with target chip

The programmer I am using is AVR USB programmer, from ABLab Solutions. The software I am using for program burn is extreme Burner AVR.

I don't think this is a problem with the driver because it says it has found an USBasp on USB port. There was an option to select the chip model, where I selected ATmega16 (because 16A) was not there. How can I solve my problem?

EDIT: The picture of the circuit: I used Zener for just-in-case voltage fluctuation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQOeRv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is the chip powered during programming?

Comment: Not from external source. doesn't the usb powers the chip @MattYoung ?

Comment: Multimeter showd very low voltage though, do i have to supply external voltage?

Comment: Double check your connections. If its not the connections, then probably the ATMEGA 16 is locked and you should by a new one. There is a way to unlock, but it's really difficult. I advise you to buy a new one and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVR chips must be powered during programming. They are NOT powered from the programmer. I would recommend reading the following Application Notes

[AVR910: In System Programming](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0943.pdf)

[AVR042: Hardware Design Considerations](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2521.pdf)

Comment: Ok, so i powered it with 5.1V DC (100mA) supply, There's the same case. Same Error!

Comment: If that's the case, then there is probably something connected wrong. Please post a picture of your set up.

Comment: Edited the post. please see now

Comment: What about the rest of the pins?

Comment: All the shown pins (6) of the uC are connected to the programmer. I've checked it many times, The connection is correct.

Comment: That error has 3 possible causes. 1. The chip isn't powered 2. One of the connections is wrong 3. The crystal isn't oscillating. I've connected things and "check it many times" only to find out the connections were wrong. What about the crystal? http://extremeelectronics.co.in/downloads/usbavrprogrammer/docs/Troubleshooting.pdf

Comment: Ah! I had completely forgotten abt the crystal. I'll try and let u know. In the meantime, i could not see any difference between 2 pins of crystal, how do i know which one should be connected to XTAL1 , and which one to  XTAL2 ?

Comment: I guess you figured it out, but for the record, crystals have no polarity, but it's important to make sure the load capacitors match manufacturer recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem

1)connections were ok .
2)drivers were installed correctly.

but same error:power on failed

I tried second mcu (Atmega32): but problem not solved same error.
I tried second usbasp : but same error.

Then finally i got it accidentally ,the problem was usbasp hardware......(i dont meant manufacturing fault)
if you see it you will find jumper connection named(CLK)
when i put the jumper on it ,it work succesfully.
connect the two leads named (CLK) on usbasp.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this problem. Was hardware issue. The clk pin of the atmega8 on the usbasp had no connection. A touch with the soldering iron and now it is working. Took me 2 days to find his little bug.

Comment: Which pin is the clk pin of atmega8. I can't find it the pin diagram :(