# Power on failed; cannot communicate with target chip error eXtreme Burner

Tags: atmega, usbasp

I checked Electronics Stackexchange and other sources, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my set-up.

Some say that I need to check my connections, which I've done many times, checking all the wiring. Some say it is something with the clock. There's also [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/138454) where @Schalonsus suggests connecting the "clk pin of ATmega8", which I can't find anywhere in the online ATmega8 pin diagrams.

Here's a snapshot of the error:

[image: screenshot]

My wiring with no external power source. I connect VCC and GND pins of USBasp directly to the ATmega8. I also tried to power the ATmega8 using an external power source (5 V) but it results in the same situation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

1. What is the "clk pin" mentioned in the above comment?
2. What's wrong with my set-up?
3. Can you provide a complete schematic on how to connect a USBasp to an ATmega8?

Comment: Has this MCU been in another circuit before, where a crystal oscillator was configured? If it was configured for a crystal, it will no longer communicate without one.

Comment: Thanks Jens! Really need your help. I just bought this brand new Atmega8 from a local store, plugged it to my brand new usbasp and these errors came out. @Jens

Comment: Did this programmer work before with another MCU or is this the first attempt? I try to check whether the problem is on the MCU side or on the programmer side.

Comment: It is first attempt

Comment: I will check what an "extreme burner" is..

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner : Replay ... First, just connect the decoupling capacitor between pin 7 and pin 8. 2- Wire the ground and Vcc of the "10 pins" USBasp connector to your breadboard respectively pin-8 pin-22 (ground) and pin-7  pin-20 (VCC) already wired. 3- wire a "Led serial with 2k resistor" between ground and Vcc. 4- Verify that atmega8 is powered, Led should light. Then add MOSI, MISO and SCK .......

Comment: See my picture atmega8 circuit diagram  ... what is labelled ISP/ISP1. At the right of this 10 pins connector there are only two wires VCC and ground, pin-2 and pin-10. No other pins wired. Use the Led+resistor to be sure of wiring. Measure voltage if necessary. I hope chip is ok.

Comment: @Antonio51 Problem persists on my breed board. I'm planning to buy the programming board itself. But it seems too big for my chip. My chip is Atmega8A-PU

Comment: When the board is too big, just "remap" the same pins.

Comment: Be aware that sometimes, you need a "high voltage" programmer, if some fuses were programmed (SPIEN). To be checked. See "parallel" programming

Answer (score 4):

ADD-on: [this link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf) for serial programming (?), as @Justme pointed to ...

[image]

But see also the whole note ...

EX: https://www.electrodragon.com/product/avr-atmega8-168-328-min-development-board/

I use [this](https://blog.zakkemble.net/avrdudess-a-gui-for-avrdude/) also for programming.

[image]

First, please, **always use the "decoupling" capacitor** at the very nearest power digital pins ...

Note that sometimes ...
I have seen that all ground pins on the "10 pins connector" are not all wired.

You can use USBasp programmer under Arduino IDE.
Just add it as a "programmer" (probably already in).
Then under "sketches", use "upload" with an external programmer.

> What is the "clk pin" mentioned in the above comment

It is the SCK pin of the MOSI, MISO for SPI communications.
But see also the first picture all above and the notes link ... (pulses on XTAL1)

[Link](https://www.instructables.com/Atmel-Studio-With-Usbasp-on-Atmega-8-Target/)

[image]

Comment: Updated the wiring. I think they're all good. The problem still persists. Thank you for your time ! :D. I missed the pin 22 in the picture but connecting it results in the same situation

Comment: But where did you connect the AVCC? How does it relate to the programming circuit in any way? Shoudn't you connect it to the programming circuit supply? And when you say you connected pin 22, we don't know if you connected it correctly.

Comment: @Justme I connected AVCC directly to VCC 5V and pin 22 directly to ground

Comment: To the programmer, or somewhere else? The last picture just shows AVCC is not connected to programmer, but to some mystery wire on positive breadboard rail, if it is even connected anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! @Justme. Hope you can guide me some more. I'm a beginner in this field. I have a 5V power source connected to the breadboard. AVVC is connected to the VCC of the power source. Is that correct or what do I have to do to make the transfer work. Thanks for your time! :D

Comment: @Justme, Antonio. Hi! If possible, could you please modify your answer to give a complete schematic on how to connect usbasp to atmeg8 to make the transfer work? It'd be kind!

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Half of the chip is unpowered because it has multiple supply pins that are left unconnected.

Comment: I followed the diagram that @Antonio51 sent. Could you tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: AVCC (pin 20, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vedZ4.png) and GND (pin 22) aren't connected.

Comment: Right ... When one uses a PCB ... these are all wired :-)

Answer (score 3):

The first error message in the display log shows "Power On failed", you must solve this first. Use a separate 5 V supply and connect +5 V to pin 7 and pin 20 of the atMega8 and 0 V (GND) to pin 8 and pin 22.
A capacitor between pin 7 and 8 is important, use something between 100 nF and 1 uF.

Now add the connections to the programmer interface as Antonio51 has shown.

According to this tutorial you must set the SPI frequency to 375 kHz or lower to not overrun the 1 MHz clock of a fresh atMega8:
https://www.instructables.com/USING-EXtreme-Burner-for-AVR-Microcontroller-Progr/

The programmer should see the supply now.

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. I once received a programmer with reverse pin assignment at one connector of the cable. Same trouble..

Comment: Is there a good alternative of not using USBASP ?\